# Why am I unable to shutdown my computer after upgrade to Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: shutdown, 23.04

I upgraded to 23.04 from 22.10 a few days ago, and it worked fine at first. Then I was unable to shutdown the computer and got stuck at a black screen after a 60-second wait.

I now have to force shutdown by hitting the power button every time. I don't recall noticing this text in previous shutdowns:

`[16256.711544] reboot: Power down`

How do fix this?

[Image of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYWFe.jpg)

[Edit]
I reinstalled the OS and the error is still happening. Sometimes it stuck on screen which has Manufacturer Logo and Ubuntu Logo after pressing the shutdown.
My PC is custom build desktop of Gtune Next Gear and USB-1 port-1 is bad and I can't fix it without breaking apart the system unit. I connected 2 monitors and first one is not using. 2nd monitor is 24" pen display and I used as a main monitor. Currently I'm using `nvidia-driver-525(proprietary,tested)` from `Additional Drivers` app.

Here is my `neofetch`:

```
OS: Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64 
Host: NG-i660 1.0 
Kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic 
Uptime: 3 mins 
Packages: 2256 (dpkg), 15 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 2560x1440 
DE: GNOME 44.0 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-7700 (8) @ 3.600GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate 
Memory: 1934MiB / 32028MiB
```

Here is the last errors from  `journalctl -b -1 -p 3` :

```
May 17 16:28:43 soe-NG-i660 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
May 17 16:29:51 soe-NG-i660 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
May 17 16:29:51 soe-NG-i660 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
May 17 16:30:23 soe-NG-i660 systemd[1]: Failed to start apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
May 17 19:21:36 soe-NG-i660 gdm-password][30678]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
May 17 19:21:37 soe-NG-i660 systemd[30693]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-30915.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
May 17 19:21:37 soe-NG-i660 systemd[30693]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-30917.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
May 17 19:21:39 soe-NG-i660 systemd[30693]: Failed to start app-gnome-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart-31555.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
```

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the make/model of your laptop, as this will be helpful in resolving your issue (and help others in the future with similar problems). I'd suggest that you run `sudo journalctl -b` and look for anything that might provide some clues regarding your shutdown issue. Post anything you find of interest directly to your question (but please don't post the entire output, as it will be lengthy). Thanks

Comment: my problem is same as, i tried GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="apm=power_off loglevel=3", however it's not work. OS name Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: Same here, Linux won't shutdown, it hangs. It seems like the issue is with drm:nv_drm_master_set, as it is the only one that appears on my machine. Also, switching the Nvidia driver to 470 from 525 didn't work, this might me related to some sys configuration that affects the function call.

Comment: same issue here